# Map variable from DTO class using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, automapper

I have two classes called `Participant` and `Screen`.

```
public class Participant 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Screen> Screens { get; set; }
}



public class Screen
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SignedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And I use a `DTO` as below:

```
public class ParticipantForDashboardDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ScreenDateTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Screen> Screens { get; set; }
}
```

In here, since I don't have `ScreenDateTime` field in my `Participant` class, I decided to get this field from `Screen` class using `AutoMapper`. Here is my `MappingProfile`:

```
CreateMap<Participant, ParticipantForDashboardDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ScreenDateTime, opt => {
                opt.MapFrom(src => src.Screens.Select(x => x.SignedDateTime));
            });
```

This returns `0001-01-01T00:00:00`. I suspect that the `SELECT` query is not the one I should use. How can I map `SignedDateTime` from `Screen` class to `ScreenDate` in the dto?

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault instead of Select.

Comment: I think you would want to use both maybe.  As in `src.Screens.Select(s => s.SignedDateTime).FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your currently using a queryable, which will return multiple result, you probably on need one, so you need to create a way to resolve the proper one, e.g sort and first or default:

```
CreateMap<Participant, ParticipantForDashboardDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ScreenDateTime, opt => {
            opt.MapFrom(src => src.Screens.Select(x => x.SignedDateTime)
                                          .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                                          .FirstOrDefault());
    });
```